# send and receive service message using rosbridge

Tags: ros, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using rosbridge 2.0 to connect to a remote computer and call a ROS service on the remote machine. I'm using the sample client below (from the the rosbride website) to make the connection and call the service:

```
  from json import dumps
  from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient
   
  class GetLoggersClient(WebSocketClient):
  
       def get_loggers(self):
           msg = {'op': 'call_service', 'service': '/rosout/get_loggers'}
           self.send(dumps(msg))
  
       def opened(self):
           print "Connection opened..."
           self.get_loggers()
  
       def closed(self, code, reason=None):
           print code, reason
  
       def received_message(self, m):
           print "Received:", m
  
  if __name__=="__main__":
       try:
           ws = GetLoggersClient('ws://127.0.0.1:9090/')
           ws.connect()
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           ws.close()
```

My question is how I can receive the output message of the service call. The output message is printed in the console by received_message(self,m), but I intend to assign this output to a variable.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168431/send-and-receive-service-message-using-rosbridge/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

m is your message. I search in m (string) the interesting data.
Example, search "level":

```
def received_message(self, m):
    #print type(m)
     print("recived => %s \n" %str(m))
     difference_topic(m)

def difference_topic(m):
  pos_level = m.find('level')
```

or

```
  if (m[n] == 'l'):
     if (m[n+1] == 'e):
           ....
```

---

Originally posted by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) with karma: 62 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-05-22**:
but m is not a global variable. How can I get the output message in other methods other than received_message(). In particular, I'd like to receive the output in the method I'm calling the service (for example inside get_loggers() in the client above). Shouldn't there be a receive() or recv() function to get the output (similar to send() )?

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-05-22**:
I edited my answer. ;-)

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-05-27**:
Thanks Alex, but is there a more elegant way to receive the message in another method? If I have multiple methods, I don't want to call them all in the received_message method. and I don't want to add another parameter (m) to all the methods as your example suggests

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-05-27**:
Also your suggested way is not going to work for methods having multiple arguments. methods similar to closed(self, code, reason=None). You can't give a value to 'code' when calling the method from within received_message()

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-05-27**:
I use "difference_topic(m)" with a argument, after I tell to other functions.
I´m sure that others methods are better, but this is enough for me in this moment. ;-)